# Batching results of a mapped collection to process all at once

Tags: automapper

Considering the simplified representations of my objects:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

and some method that returns a collection of Users like:

```
List<User> users = GetUserIds();
return users.Select(x => Mapper.Map<UserDto>(x));
```

I want, for each `User`, to call a separate lookup service to get their name. Because my lookup service will accept a list of user IDs I'd like to batch them all into a single call (single network call instead of potentially hundreds). Is this possible with any existing AutoMapper functionality? In theory it would be something like:

```
CreateMap<List<User>, List<UserDto>>...
```

with a custom resolver but it seems like a decision has been made to not allow mapping of collections.

Essentially I was just hoping to implement something more elegant than the below, which in all actuality works just fine:

```
List<User> users = GetUserIds();
var ids = new List<string>();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    ids.Add(user.Id);
}

List<UserDto> dtos = LookupNames(ids);
return dtos;
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu, I've looked through the official docs and couldn't find any that address my question, this one included.